# Convertful id=”114332″ showing on WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Does anyone have an idea why I am getting this on the right column?
[convertful id=”114332″]
[error-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWydE.png)

Comment: Please share the code or URL where you are getting this error. you gave incomplete information.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you are pasting the shortcode in the "visual" tab instead of the "code" tab.